# ffmpeg Remap Filter is not scaling for me

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, c, image-filter

I'm still new to all the stack exchange sites, so if I'm not asking this in the right place, feel free to point me in the correct direction.

Link to the filter I'm using: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/RemapFilter#no1

I'm trying to get some images dewarped using a filter I found online for ffmpeg, but I'm having some weird outputs that I don't understand. I followed the instructions I could find to a T, but when I have built it and I try to generate .pgm files for mapping using:

```
./project -x example_x.pgm -y example_y.pgm -h 1080 -w 1920 -r 1080 -c 1920 
-m equirectangular --verbose)
```

I get told "Camera mode equirectangular not implemented". Looking through the source code makes even less sense as to this error since it most certainly is a specified type in the code.

Is there anyone who knows C or ffmpeg or generating pgm files enough to help with this? I am doing this in Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS if that helps. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit: This helps a bit more in explaining what I'm trying to do too: https://github.com/prouast/equirectangular-remap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was accidentally using the code from the original filter, but the -m flag I was trying to mark it as was only available through the github version. Mistake on my part, sorry if I seriously confused anyone else.